# Cannot print to Thermal Bluetooth printer from flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, printing, bluetooth

I am trying to print to a thermal printer from my flutter app. I think the connectivity from my phone to the printer(an MHT-P11) is ok because I can print a test text from an app from the app store.

So the printer is the MHT-P11 58mm for $20 on the amazon store and i'm using the bluetooth_print package.https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print I've looked at a tutorial, read the documentation and i've still been unable to get this to work.

So I believe this to be the relavant code.

```
class _PrintTestPageState extends State<PrintTestPage>
/*   with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
*/
{
  BluetoothPrint bluetoothPrint = BluetoothPrint.instance;
  List<BluetoothDevice> _devices = [];
  String _deviceMsg = "";
  final f = NumberFormat("\$###,##.00", "en_US");

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => 
{initPrinter()});
  }

  Future<void> initPrinter() async {
    bluetoothPrint.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 2));
    if (!mounted) return;
bluetoothPrint.scanResults.listen((val) {
  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() => {_devices = val});
  if (_devices.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      _deviceMsg = "No Devices";
    });
  }
});
  }

/*
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Select Printer'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
    ),
    body: _devices.isEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: Text(_deviceMsg ?? ''),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _devices.length,
            itemBuilder: (c, i) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.print),
                title: Text(_devices[i].name ?? 'Unknown'),
                subtitle: Text(_devices[i].address ?? 'Unknown'),
                onTap: () {
                  _startPrint(_devices[i]);
                },
              );
            }));
  }

    Future<void> _startPrint(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    if (device != null && device.address != null) {
      await bluetoothPrint.connect(device);

  Map<String, dynamic> config = Map();
  config['width'] = 48;
  config['height'] = 0;
  config['gap'] = 2;

  List<LineText> list = [];
  list.add(
      LineText(type: LineText.TYPE_TEXT, x: 10, y: 10, content: 'A Title'));
  list.add(LineText(
      type: LineText.TYPE_TEXT, x: 10, y: 40, content: 'this is content'));
  list.add(LineText(
      type: LineText.TYPE_QRCODE, x: 10, y: 70, content: 'qrcode i\n'));
  list.add(LineText(
      type: LineText.TYPE_BARCODE, x: 10, y: 190, content: 'qrcode i\n'));

  await bluetoothPrint.printLabel(config, list);
}
```

}
}

I know for sure `initPrinter` works because I see my bluetooth printer along with it's name and it's mac. But nothing works when I hit `_startPrint`. I dont know if it's an error there but this _startPrint code was actually lifted from the Bluetooth print documentation and I have not been successful in printing.
Appreciate if anyone could assist me in finding my error.

Regards